# Windows 10 Task Scheduler: Execute bash script without showing up cmd

Tags: windows, bash, cmd, scheduled-tasks, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a task on my computer downloading a daily backup from my server. Basically it's:

```
bash.exe -c "cd /mnt/d/server_backups && ./download_backup.sh"
```

This does work, however it always pops up the cmd window, which wouldn't actually bother me, if it wasn't because it interrupts whatever I'm doing (gaming, watching a movie, working) and just throws me to desktop.

Changing task to "Run whether user is logged or not" doesn't work because apparently *windows session zero* (whatever that is) can't initiate calls with bash.

Is there another way to either not show up the cmd window or doing it without the SO deciding on its own that I want to have it main focused and everything else minimized?

Comment: That's a console window, not a CMD window. Like any console application, bash.exe allocates a new console if the process isn't flagged to run detached, i.e. `DETACHED_PROCESS`. But, having tested this, it seems WSL fails to initialize if the process console handle isn't set, i.e. the process has to be attached to a console. Your options are to create the console without a window (i.e. `CREATE_NO_WINDOW`) or with a hidden window via the `STARTUPINFO` `wShowWindow` field.

Comment: In either case, you need a scripting language such as Python or PowerShell that lets you control how the bash.exe process is created, since the task scheduler  doesn't provide that level of control.

Comment: Could you imagine using Cygwin instead of Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a VBS script to launch bash without a cmd.exe window, as follow :

*hidden_launcher.vbs*

```
Set WinScriptHost = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WinScriptHost.Run WScript.Arguments(0), 0
Set WinScriptHost = Nothing
```

Here, we run the 1st argument received, and 0 means `start the program hidden`.

Now set up your task in the task scheduler :

- Program to launch : `C:\Path\to\hidden_launcher.vbs`
- Arguments: `"bash.exe -c 'cd /mnt/d/server_backups && ./download_backup.sh' "`

This should do the trick !!

Comment: Looks good but it is not working for me. Putting it on task scheduler or a .bat file (to test) apparently does nothing, and executing the .vbs provokes and error "Subindex out of range" on line 2, char 1. As I have no clue about windows programming languages I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or not.

Comment: Did you put `"bash.exe -c 'cd/mnt/d/server_backups && ./download_backup.sh' "` in the arguments field of the task scheduler **with this exact quotation ?** (be sure to put the double quotes / single quotes exactly how they are written). If you try to execute the script without an argument, it will throw an error, as is looks for the 1st arg (thus the "out of range" message you got). If you want to check if the script works well, you can try to pass `"bash.exe -c 'echo it worked > /home/YOUR_USERNAME' "` and it will create a file at your linux root folder

Comment: Yes I put the arguments with this exact quotation, I copy-pasted directly from your answer actually.

Comment: I did some testing and found out this: executing from cmd `cscript hidden_launcher.vbs "bash.exe -c 'echo it worked > /home/MY_USERNAME/test.txt' "` works perfect, but not with `"bash.exe -c 'cd/mnt/d/server_backups && ./download_backup.sh > /home/MY_USERNAME/log.txt' "`, file **log.txt** is never created. Also, neither work with task scheduler. Calling to the _.vbs_ script from scheduler prompts dialog to select  program to open and waits for user response. If I put previous command in a _.bat_ file it does execute (or so it seems, console window flashes) but **test.txt** is never created.

Comment: Do you run your task with elevated permissions ? maybe `bash.exe` needs to have admin rights to execute parts of your script or to write to `/mnt/d`. Also, `cd/mnt/d/server_backups` has a typo, you need a space between `cd` and `/mnt/d/server_backups`, i.e.: `cd /mnt/d/server_backups`

Comment: Fixed the typo thanks. But I copy-pasted yours so there was no typo during my testing anyway, also tried with elevated privileges and with compatibility mode for W7 and WVista just in case. However I did notice now than the execution result on task scheduler ends with **0x1** which I think it means error. Though that's all the info I get.

Comment: fyi mine had a typo too because I copy-pasted your code :) I edited my answer 30 minutes ago to address the typo

Comment: Yep you were right. There was a typo, fixing it made the **.bat** file work on double click. But it still isn't working with task scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can use WSL like `wsl -e cd /mnt/d/server_backups && ./download_backup.sh`